# DriveInfo equivalent in WinRT/Metro App

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

I need to scan all the local drives (and the directories) in a Metro App that I'm working on. I've searched everywhere I could, but without any success. Basically, I need something similar to what is shown as an example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that metro style applications are severely restricted in the parts of the operating system they can access.  I don't believe that it is possible for a metro style app to scan arbitrary locations on the users hard disk.  You can request permissions to access the users photos, videos and documents, but outside that, your options are limited.

Comment: I pretty much got to the same conclusion now. Doesn't this mean that Metro is never going to be a full replacement? What about those system tools which need access outside of mere Pictures or Documents folder, or something like Virus Scanner?

Comment: @cod3-monk-3y: Anti-virus software has been tried and tested for the desktop world over the decades; there is really no reason to move to Metro just because everyone else is.

Comment: "Never" is a strong word, there is no way of predicting the future, and I wouldn't even begin to speculate about features in future versions of Windows.  For Windows 8, metro-style applications are restricted in what they can access.